Get clicking coordinates inclusive to parent page from iframe
I have an iframe in my page and when I click it i display a small square with information. The problem is that the coordinates given by the iframe via post message are right except when scrolling in it, because the coordinates are bigger than the parent view height. I want to know how I can make the calculation in order to display it in the right place.
I've already tried calculating the newY with the client rect and the scroll coordinates. The problem is that the scroll coordiantes are always 0 so that doesn't have an impact in the calculations. This is my useEffect:
useEffect(() => {
    const handleMessage = (event: MessageEvent) => {
      if (event.data.type === 'toolInfo' && footprintsOn) {
        const iframe = document.getElementById('titanpad') as HTMLIFrameElement;
        const iframeRect = iframe.getBoundingClientRect();
        const { x: iframeX, y: iframeY } = iframeRect;
        const iframeScrollTop = event.data.data.scrollCoordinates.scrollY;
        
        const newX = event.data.data.coordinates.x + iframeX;
        let newY = event.data.data.coordinates.y + iframeY + iframeScrollTop;
        
        // Adjust newY if it's beyond the current view bounds
        const maxYInView = window.innerHeight + window.scrollY;
        console.log(maxYInView, window.innerHeight, window.scrollY, newY)
        if (newY > maxYInView) {
          newY = maxYInView;
        }

        event.data.data.coordinates = { x: newX, y: newY };
        setToolInfoSquareData(event.data);
        setOpenToolInfo(true);
      } 
    };

    window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage);
    };
  }, [footprintsOn]);

Am i missing something in my calculation? Or what could be the correct approach for this problem.
I want something like the following example. In this case the text document would be the iframe and even if it was scrolled down I want the square to appear at the same level. (With what I have right now if i click the text and I've already scrolled down, the square appears out the view height bounds and applies a general scroll to the parent page. I just want the iframe to have scroll):


Have you tried using document.scrollTop instead of window.scrollY for the scroll value of the iframe.
You don’t show the code for how your getting the scroll position in the iframe, so it is difficult to comment further.
